# Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 Custom Layout m overdot not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, accessibility

I have created a custom keybaord layout using MS KLC1.4
I have set Alt-GR to produce the requried diacritics (ḂĊḊḞĠṀṖṠṪ)
They work in the uppercase, but the only way I can get ṁ is to toggle on capslock and press shift+Alt Gr+m
Alt Gr+m doesn't work if the caps lock is turned on (it should produce Ṁ)

I am 99% certain this is because Windows has set Ctrl + Alt + M to be "Cycle through views".

Is there a way to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

NVidia Experience was the culprit. It's set as a keyboard shortcut and those are blocking.